# Search through multidimensional Javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array set up like the following:

```
var array = [["A1", "left:81px"], ["A2", "left:145px"],...]
```

The purpose of this is to take a user input and search through this array to find the location to move an element to. If the user input is `"A1"` how can I parse through this array to set some variable equal to `"left:81px"`?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried? This is not a code writing service, and we expect people to show they have put effort into trying to solve the problem themselves. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular

Comment: Can you expand your reply? I'm not very familiar with JavaScript and don't quite understand.

Comment: @messerbill then you should know `map` is a bad recommendation for this problem ...

Comment: @messerbill `map` performs an operation on every element of the input array and produces a new output array. that has _nothing_ to do with the question being asked - we don't want to perform an operation on every element and we don't want to create a new array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `find` and some simple destructuring.

```js
var array = [
  ["A1", "left:81px"],
  ["A2", "left:145px"]
];

const [, res] = array.find(([k]) => k == "A1") || [];

console.log(res);
```

The above returns `undefined` if no value is found.

Slightly simpler code:

```js
var array = [
  ["A1", "left:81px"],
  ["A2", "left:145px"]
];

const input = "A1";
let res = "";

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i][0] == input) {
    res = array[i][1];
    break;
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: in your first example, use `array.find(...) || []` that way `[,res] = ...` will never throw an error. If no match is found, `res` will be `undefined`

Comment: OK @user633183, I'll edit my answer to improve stability.

Comment: Fixed @user633183, better now? (I don't need to add to `filter` because it's `[]` by default).

Comment: No, `filter` is worse because it will continue traversing the array even after the first match is found. The question only seeks to retrieve a _single_ value.

Comment: Okay, fixed now @user633183 - better?

Comment: `array.find(...) || "Default Value"` does not work either because `[,res] ...` will destructure the string, causing `"e"` (the second letter) to be assigned to `res` ^_^

Comment: You've just rewrite my conception for the second solution) nice man

Comment: Whoops, sorry - should I just put it in an array `|| [, "Default Value"]`?

Comment: What do you mean @AksenP?

Comment: @JackBashford `... || [, "Default Value"]` works but it's rather ugly. If you wanted to add default value functionality, I would sooner do: `const r = array.find(...); return r === undefined ? "default value" : r[1];` it's not as pretty, but it's more clear, imo. My original suggestion to add `... || []` gives `res = undefined` which matches the behavior of `find` and is probably good enough.

Comment: Cool, I'll just add that then - would you be satisfied in that instance?

Comment: Fixed @user633183.

Comment: @JackBashford looks better, but you already had my up-vote even in your first revision '^_^

Comment: My bad @user633183 - all potential offence withdrawn. Sorry for the assumption - I've just had that happen a lot where the first "improvement" commenter is the downvoter.

Comment: @JackBashford I had that suspicion - it's always awkward offering a comment on an answer with a down-vote that isn't yours. I've seen you around on the site and you're doing good work here. Keep it up and don't let the ankle biters get you down :D

Comment: Thank you so much for the positive feedback @user633183 - as one of the more experienced users on the site, both in JavaScript and more generally, I take that at very high face value.

Comment: In your second example, when I do ' i < array.length ' it tells me that the array is undefined. Any clue as to why?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the inner arrays are always structured like `[key, value]`:

```js
// this is your array.
const array = [["A1", "left:81px"], ["A2", "left:145px"]]

// user input:
const query = "A1";

// find an inner array in array whose first element matches the user input
const [, result] = array.find(([key]) => key === query) || []

console.log(result);
```

If possible, you should use a better (map-like) data structure for this:

```js
const data = {
  A1: 'left:81px',
  A2: 'left:145px'
};

const query = 'A1';

const result = data[query];
console.log(result);
```

The array version has a linear runtime where as the second one is constant time. If you will do this lookup often, it is worth converting your array representation to an object

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use Object.fromEntries to convert key ,value pair array to object - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

1. Convert key-value pairs array to object using Object.fromEntries.
2. Find value using key value like A1,A2

working code sample

```js
var arr = [["A1", "left:81px"], ["A2", "left:145px"]]
function findVal(word, arr){
  var obj = Object.fromEntries(arr)
  return obj[word]
  
}
console.log(findVal('A1', arr))
```

**Option 2:** Using reduce and converting key ,value pair array to object one time and use for further searches everytime and also for better browser compatibility compare to Object.fromEntries

```js
var arr = [["A1", "left:81px"], ["A2", "left:145px"]]
var obj = arr.reduce((acc,v)=>{
    acc[v[0]] = v[1]
    return acc
  }, {})
console.log(obj['A1'])
```

Comment: the major downside to this answer is the entire input needs to be transformed before the answer can be returned - this is wasteful compared to approaches which stop reading the input as soon as the match is encountered.

Comment: @user633183, one approach is to convert it to object one time for making easy for further searches , instead of looping for every search

Comment: Correct, if many lookups are required, a data type offering better search capabilities would offer a much better performance. Consider [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in this case.

Comment: @user633183, updated option 2 to create object from that array and using it for every other following searches

Comment: Your second solution `reduce` suffers from the same problem. It will traverse the entire input array even though a result could be returned sooner. Using `reduce` like this is effectively writing `Object.fromEntries` by hand.

Comment: yes@user633183, I am sure that search will be happening multiple times for that array , it suffers first time and makes easy for next searches with better time complexity from second time rather than looping everytime

Comment: I agree a more suitable data structure would allow for much better answers to this question